# C# not all code paths return a value CreateArmy

Tags: c#

I'm having a huge problem with this. My CreateArmy method keeps returning the error: Not all code paths return a value. I'm positive they all return a value:

```
public string CreateArmy(string inputFile)
{
   string grabFile = inputFile + ".txt";
   int counter = 0;
   string line;
   try
   {
      // Read the file and display it line by line.
      StreamReader file = new StreamReader(grabFile);

      while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         char[] fixedCommands = line.Remove(0, 3).ToCharArray();
         commands[0] = fixedCommands[0];
         commands[1] = fixedCommands[1];
         commands[2] = fixedCommands[2];
         byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
         commands[].Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
         counter++;
      }
      char[] newcommands = new string(commands).Remove(0, 3).ToCharArray();

      file.Close();
      MessageBox.Show("There are " + counter + " robots!");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please tell me the .txt file type. Do not include the .txt extension.");
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have declared that the method will return a string, but it doesn't. You don't have a single `return` statement. Showing a messagebox isn't the same as returning a string.

Comment: There's no return statement in your code....so it won't return anything.

Comment: the infamous return leaves you in a "void"...or...the "void" that never returns...

Answer (score 0):

Your method is supposed to return a string

```
public string CreateArmy(string inputFile)
```

However, nowehre in your method is there a `return` statement that does so.

If the return statement is not required, then make the method void (i.e. no return):

```
public void CreateArmy(string inputFile)
```

Otherwise, ensure the correct data is returned from **all** possible code paths.

Answer (score 0):

Either don't setup the `CreateArmy()` function to return a string, OR add a return statement to your code.

Solution #1:

```
public void CreateArmy(string inputFile)
        {
        string grabFile = inputFile + ".txt";
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        try
        {
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(grabFile);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] fixedCommands = line.Remove(0, 3).ToCharArray();
            commands[0] = fixedCommands[0];
            commands[1] = fixedCommands[1];
            commands[2] = fixedCommands[2];
            byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            commands[].Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
            counter++;
        }

        char[] newcommands = new string(commands).Remove(0, 3).ToCharArray();

        file.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("There are " + counter + " robots!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please tell me the .txt file type. Do not include the .txt extension.");
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

---

Solution #2:

```
public string CreateArmy(string inputFile)
        {
        string grabFile = inputFile + ".txt";
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        try
        {
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(grabFile);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] fixedCommands = line.Remove(0, 3).ToCharArray();
            commands[0] = fixedCommands[0];
            commands[1] = fixedCommands[1];
            commands[2] = fixedCommands[2];
            byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            commands[].Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
            counter++;
        }

        char[] newcommands = new string(commands).Remove(0, 3).ToCharArray();

        file.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("There are " + counter + " robots!");

        return null;  // OR return some other string value!
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please tell me the .txt file type. Do not include the .txt extension.");
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a return statement to return a string in your "Try" block, as well as in your "Catch" block in case an exception is thrown.

If you are not meaning to return anything from the method call, set your return type on the method to "void".