# What value should this method be returning?

Tags: c#, methods, error-handling

Wrote this method and it keeps telling me that not all code paths return a value. I can't figure out what value should be being returned.

```
public int SelectionSort()
{

    reset();
    for (int scan = 1; scan <= work.Length - 1; scan++)
    {
        min = scan;
        max = work[scan];

        for (int i = 0; i < work.Length - scan; i++)
        {
            if (work[i] < max)
            {
                min = work[i];
                max = i;

            }
        }
        Swap(work[min], work[scan]);

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't return anything!

Comment: Your declaration says the method must return an int.  either return an int or change the declaration to void

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507197/c-sharp-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-createarmy, or many of [the other 665 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+not+all+code+paths+return+a+value) relating to the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

it should not return a value , because there is not fail or success  scenario remove simply remove the return type. you can however have this method throw exceptions for error in parameters

```
public void SelectionSort()
{
    if (work == null )  throw new ArgumentException("work is null");  
    ....
}
```